# Google Calendar set up failed

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, google

I was trying to set up Google Calendar on my new Mac. After following the steps from [this Google support article](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en), I ran into this absolutely useless error message:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

While setting up the Calendar, when my wifi was disconnected I got the same message. Then I used my 3G modem for fast and continuous connection. It resolved the issue.